# Airbnb Superset Datasource Configuration for SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise, apache-superset, datastax-startup

I am using Spark 1.6.2 (from the Datastax Enterprise Edition => DSE 5.0.4) and Python 2.7 
 
When I give

```
from impala.dbapi import connect    
Conn = connect (host = '172.31.12.201', port = 7077, user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxx1111', database = 'test_database', auth_mechanism = 'PLAIN')
```

it just hangs and never comes out 
 spark master runs at 172.31.12.201 on port 7077

My configuration in superset is as below

```
SQLAlchemy URI => impala://172.31.12.201:7077/test_database
Extra => {
"metadata_params": {},
"engine_params": {"connect_args": {"user": "xxxx", "password": "xxxx1111"}} }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to start dse spark thrift server as below

```
dse -u <username> -p <password> spark-sql-thriftserver start
```

This will start the hive server in DSE cluster on port 10000